# OData with .NET 6 and NewtonSoft and Custom Query Attribute Stops working after a short period of time

Tags: .net, .net-core, json.net, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been experimenting with OData on a .NET 6 Blazor Client/Server app but I've now noticed that after a short period of time (maybe 10 or 20 minutes), OData just stops working at all on my OData enabled endpoints. Refreshing the Swagger doco or the endpoint route doesn't do anything, but refreshing the main site seems to kick it off again.

This is how I'm hooking it up, as I'm also using NewtonSoft for JsonPatch:

```
        var maxTop = Configuration.GetValue<int>("ODataOptions:MaxTop");
        services
            .AddControllers(options => options.Filters.Add<ApiExceptionFilterAttribute>())
            .AddOData(options => options.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().SetMaxTop(maxTop))
            .AddODataNewtonsoftJson();
```

And then I just use the EnableQuery attribute on routes, but I've actually extended it with the following custom attribute:

```
public class CustomEnableQueryAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public CustomEnableQueryAttribute()
    {
        // override the page size using what's in config
        PageSize = Startup.Configuration.GetValue<int>("ODataOptions:PageSize");
    }

    // Throw an exception that can be handled in the Api Exception Filter
    public override void ValidateQuery(HttpRequest request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        try
        {
            base.ValidateQuery(request, queryOptions);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ODataQueryValidationException(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

So say I just want to test returning the id's: api/v1/entities?%24select=id
It works fine, but then after 10 or 20 minutes, I go back and refresh the page, and then it returns me all entities with all properties again; no OData routes work. Even in Swagger, the same behaviour, no errors, just as if the EnableQuery or circumvented?

Here is the controller:

```
[ApiController]
[CustomApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class MyController : ApiControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [CustomEnableQuery]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IList<Dto>>> Get()
    {
        return Ok(await Mediator.Send(new GetQuery()));
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on what might be happening here? Should I just use the EdmModel rather than the EnableQuery attributes?

Comment: Looks like it might be the wrapping of the result in ActionResult (in this case Ok()). I'm just testing it out properly, but when running a few different controllers with different changes, it seems that AFTER the method without the OK is run, then the ones with OK actually work as well, but not BEFORE it is run, which is quite interesting too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've worked out the problem. I wanted to make the Actions consistent, and all return ActionResult, so wrapped the list in an OK() method.

However, when I removed that and only return the IList, OData seems to work without fail so far.

```
[ApiController]
[CustomApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class MyController : ApiControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [CustomEnableQuery]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<IList<Dto>> Get()
    {
        return await Mediator.Send(new GetQuery());
    }
}
```

Reading through this again, I can see it should work, and I should be aiming to return an IQueryable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/first-odata-api

*Returning System.Linq.IQueryable or ActionResult enables OData to translate queries to SQL queries using ef core capabilities. Returning other types such as IEnumerable causes OData to perform queries in the app.*

However, even when using IQueryable and wrapping with ActionResult it didn't seem to work for me.